# Recognizing Unicode numbers from different languages

Tags: unicode

In Unicode every language will have their own number.  For example ASCII has "3", Japanese has "３",   and so on.  How can I identify a three no matter what unicode byte it is represented by?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about normative properties ***Decimal digit value***, ***Digit value*** and  ***Numeric value***   in [UnicodeData File Format](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/3.0-Update/UnicodeData-3.0.0.html):

> ***Decimal digit value*** *normative* This is a numeric field. If the character has the decimal digit property, as specified in Chapter 4 of
>   the Unicode Standard, the value of that digit is represented with an
>   integer value in this field.
>
> ***Digit value*** *normative* This is a numeric field. If the character represents a digit, not necessarily a decimal digit, the
>   value is here. This covers digits which do not form decimal radix
>   forms, such as the compatibility superscript digits.
>
> ***Numeric value***   *normative* This is a numeric field. If the character has the numeric property, as specified in Chapter 4 of the
>   Unicode Standard, the value of that character is represented with an
>   integer or rational number in this field. This includes fractions as,
>   e.g., "1/5" for U+2155 VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH Also included are
>   numerical values for compatibility characters such as circled numbers.

For instance, Python's `unicodedata` module provides access to the Unicode Character Database which defines character properties for all Unicode characters, see implementation: [unicodedata — Unicode Database](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html):

```
import unicodedata

numchars = '\u0033','\u00B3','\u0663','\u06F3','\u07C3','\u0969','\uFF13','\u2155'

for numchar in numchars:
    print( numchar
        , unicodedata.decimal( numchar, -1)
        , unicodedata  .digit( numchar, -1)
        , unicodedata.numeric( numchar, -1)
        , unicodedata   .name( numchar, '? ? ?') )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ==> D:\test\Python\Py3\41045800.py
>
> 3 3 3 3.0 DIGIT THREE
>
> ³ -1 3 3.0 SUPERSCRIPT THREE
>
> ٣ 3 3 3.0 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT THREE
>
> ۳ 3 3 3.0 EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT THREE
>
> ߃ 3 3 3.0 NKO DIGIT THREE
>
> ३ 3 3 3.0 DEVANAGARI DIGIT THREE
>
> ３ 3 3 3.0 FULLWIDTH DIGIT THREE
>
> ⅕ -1 -1 0.2 VULGAR FRACTION ONE FIFTH
>
> ==>
> ```

P.S. Given Python example as the question is not tagged to any particular language.