# Converting characters like '³' to Integer in Python

Tags: python

I have this character '³' in my dataset that I'm processing on top of.

Generic Idea is to detect if a character is an integer, convert it into an integer and process on top of it.

```py
>>> x = '³'
>>> x.isdigit() # Returns True
True
```

Python detects this character as a digit. But raises the following error when I try to convert it

```py
>>> int(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '³'
```

I would like it if such characters could also be converted to integer, to ease my further processing

Not sure if this helps, but here is my locale info

```py
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: I need to know if the values of x will always be '3' if not what is the range of items will it be ?

Comment: I'm assuming it would be in the range 0-9. I know I can simply map every single one of those digits to an integer to convert it. But I'm curious why python detects it as a digit and can't convert it

Comment: Check difference between `isdigit()` vs `isdecimal()`

Comment: because yes its a digit but it has a different Unicode character so that is why it recognized as a digit but cant convert it to integer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recognizing Unicode numbers from different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045800/recognizing-unicode-numbers-from-different-languages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use unicodedata and NFKC to convert it
here is a detailed code with some error handling

```
import unicodedata

x = '³'
try:
    regular_digit = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', x)
    integer_value = int(regular_digit)
    print(integer_value)
except ValueError:
    print(f"'{x}' is not a convertible superscript digit.")
```